# How to find all index pairs of unequal elements in vector (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector

Lets say I have the following vector in Matlab:

```
V = [4, 5, 5, 7];
```

How can I list (in a n-by-2 matrix for example) all the index pairs corresponding to unequal elements in the vector. For example for this particular vector the index pairs would be:

```
index pairs (1, 2) and (1, 3) corresponding to element pair (4,5)

index pair (1, 4) corresponding to element pair (4,7)

index pairs (2, 4)  and (3, 4) corresponding to element pair (5,7)
```

The reason I need this is because I have a cost-function which takes a vector such as `V` as input and produces a cost-value.

I want to see how does the random swapping of **two differing** elements in the vector affect the cost value (using this for steepest descent hill climbing).

The order of the index pairs doesn't also matter. For my purposes `(1,2)` is the same as `(2,1)`.

For example if my cost-function was `evalCost()`, then I could have `V = [4, 5, 5, 7]` and

```
evalCost(V) = 14
```

whereas for `W = [4, 7, 5, 5]` the cost could be:

```
evalCost(W) = 10
```

How to get the list of "swapping" pair indexes in Matlab. Hope my question is clear =)

Comment: Its a completely different approach, but I believe that `pdist2` might make you happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `bsxfun` and then the two-ouput version of `find` to get the pairs. `triu` is applied to the output of `bsxfun` to consider only one of the two possible orders.

```
[ii jj] = find(triu(bsxfun(@ne, V, V.')));
pairs = [ii jj];
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the cost function part, but the first part is simple:

```
[a,b]=unique(V)
C = combnk(b,2)
```

`C` contains the indices, and `V(C)` the values:

```
C = combnk(b,2)

C =

     1     2
     1     4
     2     4

V(C)

ans =

     4     5
     4     7
     5     7
```

Comment: +1 Thank you @Daniel. You don't have to matter about the cost-function part, I was just trying to explain my motivation behind the problem. The point is I just need the indexes :) Then I evaluate the new swapped vector with the cost-function =) Did that make it clear? I think you're answer is everything I need. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Daniel what about in the more general case? I think I might need that one too =) I updated my question. What if redundant pairs ARE allowed? See my updated question =)